# Conservation of Mometum in integral form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, momentum

> [image]
>
> Water is pumped from one reservoir into a another. The pipe expands after a lenght of $L/2$ to a diameter of $d$.
>
> Given: $\dot{V}_p, \rho_w, d, \eta, L, p_p$

The previos tasks allowed to solve for all unknown velocities and the friction forces $F_f$.

Now I have to calculate the pressure drop $\Delta p_v$ across the pipe.

Although $p_p$ is given, it is not stated what pressure that is. We assume it's the pressure after the pump.

The solution suggests that when balancing all momemtum and pressure forces that the difference in the pressure forces is $\Delta p_v \pi d^2$.

My question regards the concept of the selected control volumes and its influences. My idea is that in the first case you would assume a pressure force (unknown) that works  like shown in the image, across the area that is not "covered" by the pipe on the left side.

[image]

Or maybe it is a pressure force that works on the inside after the expansion. (Wrong direction in the image).

[image]

Without knowledge of any pressure force I'm sure you can just add all pressure forces and say the sum is $\Delta p_v$. This is what was done in the soltion and that makes sense to me, since I only want to know the difference, no explicit values for each force.

**Question:** Are both my drafts correct? How can I physically imagine the unknown force? Is the unknown force the reason why I can reference all my pressure forces on the area with the diameter of d?